# Angular Controller Instantiated Multiple Times

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-controller

I have an Angular controller loaded in a view:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <p ng-bind-html="content"></p>
</div>
```

This partial is loaded into different views, and as a result the controller gets instantiated multiple times. In the controller, I'm detecting for location change:

```
angular.module('MyApp')
  .controller('HintCtrl', function ($scope, $rootScope) {
    $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function () {
       alert("HI");
    });
});
```

Each time I change my location, this fires once for each time the controller was ever loaded. How can I have this run only once?

Comment: Maybe you should handle the event in a parent controller. This is how angular works and it's coherent that each controller sees the event.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The point is that Controllers are not singleton. You gonna have one new instance for each of the elements.

What you can do, is to use this on a [service](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.creating_services), and this one is singleton.

You could do something like this:

```
angular.module('MyApp')
  .controller('HintCtrl', function ($scope, Alerter) {
    Alerter.doSomething();
  })

  .service('Alerter', function($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function () {
      alert("HI");
    });

    this.doSomething = function() {
      ...
    };
  });
```